# SSAS connection from Python

Tags: python, ssas, olap

Does anyone know of a Python package to connect to SSAS multidimensional and/or SSAS tabular that supports MDX and/or DAX queries. I know of olap.xmla but that requires an HTTP connection. I am looking for a Python equivalent of olapR in R. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [xmla](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmla/) python lib. See [my blog](http://blog.soft-prestidigitation.com/ssas-via-python.html) for more usage details. I've tried IronPython with Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DLL as well ([see an example](https://gist.github.com/dankor/bd8b944820a902e3f90a12231cb95a64)) and it worked, but xmla is simply enough for most of things.

Comment: Danylo - thanks - do you have reference to an IronPython example

Comment: Something like that: https://gist.github.com/dankor/bd8b944820a902e3f90a12231cb95a64
But, again, xmla is simpler and doesn't require a client .NET runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Python does not support to include .net dll, but IronPython does, we had a MS BI automation project before with IronPython to connect SSAS, it is a nice experience.

www.mdx-helper.com

Comment: Tom - thanks - do you have a reference to an IronPython example